# Riemann Zeta Function for 0<s<1

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

In Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory", there is a definition for the Riemann Zeta Function for $0<s<1$.

[image]

Is there a justification for this formula?

Comment: analytic continuation, obviously

Comment: Yes; you can use Riemann-Stieltjes integration for the summation and obtain some cancellation. What is left will converge.